# Objective-c calling a method from class method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to access an instance method from a class method. I am getting this error

> +[ActiveVC goToDashBoard]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x112010
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ActiveVC goToDashBoard]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class 0x112010'

**My code**

```
+ (void) removeClosedVisitor:(NSString *) visitorID{

    for (NSInteger i = activelist.count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        ActiveItemObject *item = [activelist objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([visitorID isEqualToString:item.VisitorId]) {
            NSLog(@"Removing Visitor from Active List -- %@", visitorID);
            [activelist removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            //[self.incommingTable reloadData];

//            NSDictionary *activeDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
//            activeDictionary = [activelist mutableCopy];
//            
//            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
//             postNotificationName:@"PassData"
//             object:nil
//             userInfo:activeDictionary];

            [[self class] goToDashBoard];
        }
    }
}



- (void) goToDashBoard{
    NSLog(@"Segue to Dashboard");
    UITabBarController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id_tabView"];
    [dvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentViewController:dvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

can some one help me to fix this issue . tnx.

Comment: `- (void) goToDashBoard` is an instance method. If you want to make it a class method, Accessible without an instance, change the signature to `+ (void) goToDashBoard`

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an instance of your class or convert your class to a singleton. For example: `[[ActiveVC sharedInstance] goToDashBoard];`

Here's how you create a Singleton Class:

First, create a New file and subclass it from `NSObject`. Name it anything, we will use `CommonClass` here. Xcode will now generate CommonClass.h and CommonClass.m files for you.

In your `CommonClass.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CommonClass : NSObject {
}
+ (CommonClass *)sharedObject;
@property NSString *commonString;
@end
```

In your `CommonClass.m` File:

```
#import "CommonClass.h"

@implementation CommonClass

+ (CommonClass *)sharedObject {
    static CommonClass *sharedClass = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClass = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedClass;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.commonString = @"this is string";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call instance method then you will need an instance variable so create instance variable of this class and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have an instance anywhere? If not you will have to create one:

```
[self.sharedInstance goToDashBoard]

[[self alloc] init] goToDashBoard]
```

I assume you do have an instance, because its looks like its a view controller. In which case I suggest you pass the instance into the static method.

```
+ (void) removeClosedVisitor:(NSString *) visitorID viewController: (xxx) viewController {
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `goToDashBoard` a class method. Since you are not creating any instance here, if it is not a class method then it can't be executed.

```
+ (void) goToDashBoard
```